# Create new account in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to create a new sandbox test account on PayPal Developer, I got the following error message:

> We're sorry but something went wrong.Please delete this account and try again

I've tried several different passwords incl. special characters without success.
The accounts I've created are visible but not "verified" by PayPal and I can't access them on the sandbox website.

Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal accounts, testing and sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367818/paypal-accounts-testing-and-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all of your cookies and cache before logging into the developer.paypal.com site and creating an account.  Also what browser are you using?  If you haven't tried a different browser, try using a different browser when logging in and creating an account.

Answer (score 0):

Tha answer is actually simple.  Just set the paypal starting balance to a value less than $5000.

As I found here:
http://believeinmiraclesx.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/paypal-sandbox-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-please-delete-this-account-and-try-again/

Wouldn't it be nice if they'd just give a nice clear concise error message.