# PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR in PayPal iOS & Android SDK

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Today I have a problem with PayPal checkout in my iOS application.

After user login, I receive an error:

> PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - There was a problem setting up this payment. Please visit the PayPal website to check your account. (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: caf4fb9d7f20c [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.12.2]

The buyer account has enough balance and I think is ok. Is there a way to find a reason for this error?

Comment: I think you enter wrong price type

Comment: mmm i don't think :(

Comment: Have you tried a different buyer account?

Comment: Yes, but it work only the first time. After that paypal return the error again

Comment: Unfortunately there were quite a few issues with the sandbox environment yesterday that may have caused this.  Can you please test again and, if it's still happening, please provide the debug ID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15380006/2699432

Comment: @DigitalBrain_DEV Have u got your solution?

Answer (score 0):

If any one still have this issue, check your buyer/seller info.
I had the same issue. I was using an Indian buyer account. But it started working when I tested with a new USA buyer account and currency USD.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to solve the issue. But can you confirm whether this problem exists during testing with a sandbox account or does this will it exists for a live account ?

Comment: @RoshanS this will only exist for live environment.