# paypal sandbox not working and display popup error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, paypal

Error i Log:

> PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[4326:177457] PayPal SDK: Request has failed
>   with error: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - There was a problem setting up
>   this payment. Please visit the PayPal website to check your account.
>   (422) | PayPal Debug-ID: bcb3771abac29 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK
>   2.11.4]

popup error:

> There was a problem setting up this payment. please visit paypal
>   website to check your account.

I checked account. Its valid, have fund, have business and personal is same country currency. I didnt find what problem occurs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32844636/1402846

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15380006/2699432